# После интерпретации выдает MemoryError

Tags: python

```
def handle_magicians(list, list2):
    for element in list:
        'Great' + element
        list.append(element)
    for element in list2:
        'Hi, {}!'.format(element)
        list2.append(element)
    print(list, list2)

magicians = ['peter', 'maggy']

magicians_copy = magicians[:]

handle_magicians(magicians, magicians_copy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты увеличиваешь список во время его итерации:

```
for element in list:
    list.append(element)
```

Та же самая проблема с `list2`. Поскольку список все время растет, цикл никогда не остановится, увеличивая список до размеров, которые перестают помещаться в отведенную процессу память.